# How to specify a username and password to download a crate from a Cargo alternative registry?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm testing the [alternative registry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/registries.html) feature. How I make Cargo be able to download a crate if this crate is behind HTTP basic authentication?

According to the [Registry Definition Specifications](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2141-alternative-registries.md#registry-definition-specification), I have to provide both in *.cargo/credentials* like this:

```
[registries.my-registry]
user = "tim"
password = "topsecret"
```

Testing it with curl works fine:

```
# curl -u tim:topsecret https://my.registry/api/v1/crates/krate/0.1.0/download
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal.
```

However, Cargo gets an `Authentication Required` response:

```
error: failed to download from `https://my.registry/api/v1/crates/krate/0.1.0/download`

Caused by:
  failed to get 200 response from `https://my.registry/api/v1/crates/krate/0.1.0/download`, got 401
```

Comment: Did you find out, Tim?